# Remove numbers from a list that begins with a specif digit

Tags: java, list, arraylist, integer

For example, i have this list

```
List<Integer> list = new ArrayList<>();

        list.add(64);
        list.add(5);
        list.add(10);
        list.add(66);
        list.add(7);
        list.add(68);
```

How i remove only the numbers that begins with "6"

Comment: `list.removeIf(n -> n.toString().startsWith("6"));`

Comment: Where are you stuck? Is it finding the numbers that start with 6, removing them, or ... ?

Comment: `int firstDigit = (int) (number / (int)Math.pow(10, (int)Math.log10(number)))` will return the first digit of a number, for example, `list.removeIf(n -> 6 == (int) (n / (int)Math.pow(10, (int)Math.log10(n))));`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several ways how you can approach this task:

- using an `Iterator`;
- by utilizing so-called **traditional for loop**;
- with a help of **Stream IPA**;
- using method `Collection.removeIf()`.

**Note** that attempt to address this problem using **enhanced for loop** (sometimes called "for-each" loop) will lead to `CuncurrentModdificationException` at runtime (if the collection will get modified). Because under hood iteration over a *collection* with *enhanced for loop* makes use of an **iterator** that is provided by the *collection*. And while iteration happens *collection* must **not** be modified other than by means of the iterator itself, i.e. by using method `remove()` of the *iterator*.

To iterate over the collection with an *iterator* firstly you have to an instance of the `Iterator` by invoking `.iterator()` on the collection. Methods of the `Iterator` class `hasNext()` and `next()` are used to check whether the next element exists and to move to the next element respectively.

```
public static List<Integer> removeNumberIfStarsWith(List<Integer> source, int target) {
    List<Integer> copy = new ArrayList<>(source); // defencive copy to preserve the source list intact

    Iterator<Integer> iterator = copy.iterator();
    while (iterator.hasNext()) {
        Integer item = iterator.next();
        if (item.toString().startsWith(String.valueOf(target))) {
            iterator.remove();
        }
    }
    return copy;
}
```

To implement this task with **traditional for loop** we have to keep in mind that removal of elements must not mess the indices that are haven't visited yet. Probably the simplest way to do it is to iterate in reversed order starting from the last index.

**Note:**

- there are **two** flavors of `remove()` method available with an instance of the `List` interface. One accepts an `int` *index* another an `object` that has to be removed. And this case is interesting because it is a choice between `remove(int)` and `remove(Integer)`. Remember that when an overloaded method is called if a version of this method with exactly the *same set of parameter types* (same types in the same order) exists, the compiler will map this version to that method call. I.e. method `remove(int)` will be invoked since we are passing a primitive type `int`.

The code for this task with traditional for loop might look like:

```
public static List<Integer> removeNumberIfStarsWith(List<Integer> source, int target) {
    List<Integer> copy = new ArrayList<>(source); // defencive copy to preserve the source list intact

    for (int i = copy.size() - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
        Integer item = copy.get(i);
        if (item.toString().startsWith(String.valueOf(target))) {
            copy.remove(i);
        }
    }
    return copy;
}
```

Since this question is related to basic operations with collections I don't assume the knowledge of *lambda expressions* and *streams*. But for completeness and for *future readers*, I'll provide two other options that I've mentioned above.

[*for information on lambda expressions and functional interfaces read this*](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/lambdaexpressions.html)

[to get familiar with Stream IPA take a look at this tutorial](https://www.oracle.com/technical-resources/articles/java/ma14-java-se-8-streams.html)

The condition inside the method `filter()` in the stream pipeline and  [`Collection.removeIf()`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Collection.html#removeIf(java.util.function.Predicate)) must defenetelly look familiar to you. Both method expect [`Predicate`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/function/Predicate.html) a function that takes an object and returns a boolean value. `Collection.removeIf()` will remove the element if the predicate returns `true`, but `filter()` does the opposite it'll retain the element if the predicate returns `true`.

So stream-based implementation might look like this:

```
public static List<Integer> removeNumberIfStarsWith(List<Integer> source, int target) {
    return source.stream()
            .filter(item -> !item.toString().startsWith(String.valueOf(target)))
            .collect(Collectors.toList());
}
```

Solution with `Collection.removeIf()`:

```
public static List<Integer> removeNumberIfStarsWith(List<Integer> source, int target) {
    List<Integer> copy = new ArrayList<>(source); // defencive copy to preserve the source list intact

    copy.removeIf(item -> item.toString().startsWith(String.valueOf(target)));
    return copy;
}
```

`main()`

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    List<Integer> list = List.of(64, 5, 10, 66, 7, 68);

    System.out.println(list);
    System.out.println(removeNumberIfStarsWith(list, 6)); // value 6 provided as an argument and not hardcoded inside the methods
}
```

**Output** (for all the versions)

```
[64, 5, 10, 66, 7, 68]
[5, 10, 7]
```

Comment: thanks for the answer and awesome explanation!

Answer (score 0):

for example, you want to delete the numbers starting with 6
you can convert each int to a list while traversing the list and check if the first character of the string is "6". if it is 6 remove that number from the list

```
    for(int i: list)
    {
    String s= Integer.toString(i);
    if(s.charAt(0)=='6')
    {
    list.remove(new Integer(i));
    }
    }
```

Comment: That's how you get a ConcurrentModificationException.

Answer (score 0):

List result = list.stream().filter(a -> !a.toString().startsWith("6")).collect(Collectors.toList());

result.forEach(System.out::println);

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).